# Strapi API cannot retrieve data

Tags: node.js, strapi

i have collection in strapi named *movie*, in there i have 24 data.
[image: movie collection]
but after retrieve movie data via API, i just get 0 rows data, im sure the endpoint status is 200 and no error.

I used default controller strapi 4 with no customitation.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

damn..after stuck for few hours, finally i have fix this problem. i know strapi 4 make an additional setting on **ContentType-Builder**. On **ContentType Builder->Advanced Settings** just disabled/turn off the **Draft/Publish** fiture.